# Amount of time between timestamps && "true"

Tags: c#

I have a list of GateEvent objects in `eventList` and they have properties `Employee`, `GateTitle`, `Timestamp`, `InsidePremises`, `EntryGranted`.

Each employee has 1 gate ID assigned to them. If they try to enter through gates that are not assigned to them `EntryGranted` returns `false`.

```
foreach(GateEvent x in eventList)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{x.Employee} | {x.GateTitle} | {x.Timestamp} | {x.EntryGranted} | {x.InsidePremises}");
}
```

Loop above returns something like this:

```
...
John Doe | Assembly line | 2022-10-06 08:51:27 | true | true // enters
John Doe | Sales office | 2022-10-06 09:41:07 | false | true // can't go through - stays in assembly line
John Doe | Assembly line| 2022-10-06 10:00:08 | true | false // leaves assembly line
John Doe | Sales office | 2022-10-06 10:10:05 | false | false // can't go through - is not at work
John Doe | Assembly line | 2022-10-06 11:53:00 | true | true // enters
John Doe | Management | 2022-10-06 12:00:00 | false | true // can't go through - stays in assembly line
John Doe | Assembly line | 2022-10-06 14:03:40 | true | false // leaves assembly line
...
```

John Doe can only go through *Assembly line* (`EntryGranted = true`) and can't go to *Sales office* (`EntryGranted = false`).
If John Doe enters to *Assembly* and there's no previous `InsidePremises` value, it means that it's first event of the day and John enters the *Assembly line*.
If John Doe goes through their assigned gates and previous `InsidePremises = true`, `InsidePremises` is changed to `false`, meaning John Doe left *Assembly line*.

I need a way to calculate the duration inside *Assembly line*, duration between each `InsidePremises = true`  and `InsidePremises = false` block.

Could anyone please assist? Is there a way to calculate it without nested `if` statements in `for` loop?

Comment: It would be easier when you create a new single row and set the entertime when John enters a premises and when he leaves set the leave time. This way you have can calculate the time inside premises with a single row.

Comment: You want to "group by" person and gate, then you want to look at the difference between when a flag was true and false. What have you tried so far?